# Setting colors for prompt in Git Bash on Windows

Tags: git, bash, msysgit

I've successfully played around with some of the color settings in the Git Bash on Windows - I'm able to set a few things, like the colors of the local, the current and remote branches in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[color "branch"]
current = cyan bold
local = cyan 
remote = red
```

But what I haven't managed to change are the colors of the prompt - the `username@machine` at the beginning of the line (in the yellow rectangle in my screenshot), and the project and branch I'm currently on (purple rectangle).

[image]

Is there a way to influence those, too? Which `.gitconfig` settings do I need to set to change those colors?

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`? What happens if you say `PS1=""`?

Comment: I have a `.bashrc` file with a few bash alias - but no `bash_profile`

Comment: @bitmask: adding a `SET PS1=""` line to `.bashrc` doesn't appear to do anything at all ...

Comment: In normal `bash` you can control the prompt solely by specifying it in the `PS1` variable, so if you override it `""` from the command line, the prompt should disappear (confirming that you can design it, by changing your `PS1` environment variable).

Comment: Just ask google for `PS1 bash`. It gives you tons of tutorials and alike.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` you can set your prompt using the `PS1` variable (which is likely set to a global value in `/etc/profile` or another file in `/etc` which may be distribution dependent).

Here's an example:

```
PS1='\[\033[1;36m\]\u@\h:\[\033[0m\]\[\033[1;34m\]\w\[\033[0m\] \[\033[1;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\$ '
```

In order for the command substitution to work, you need `shopt -s promptvars` which is the default.

This will output the user and hostname in cyan, the current directory in blue and the git branch in green on terminals that work with `TERM=xterm-color`.

See [`man 5 terminfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) and [`man tput`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) for more information about terminal controls.

Comment: Great ! Thanks - you learn something new every day here on Stackoverflow!

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact rules in all situations (interactive or not) but you may need to create a `.bash_profile` which then calls the `.bashrc` with this line: `[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered, that in `.bashrc` file located in your user folder, there is part of script:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

that when uncommented, will add to `PS1` variable the bit of colors:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

otherwise, plain prompt is set.

In general, I'd suggest to see what's happening in this script, as it's a final configuration step in launching Git Bash.

And extra tip, to apply changes without opening and closing the terminal, you can:

```
source ~/.bashrc
#same as
. ~/.bashrc
```