# How can I see colors like mac terminal in gitbash on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, windows-8.1, git-bash

I am doing rails development on windows 8. I am using gitbash as commandline tool. The issue is that the commands and outputs are all showing in plain white color, which is quite hard to read. But in mac its all nicely shown by changing colors for specific tasks. Is it possible to change the color in gitbash  on windows aswell or is there any other commandline tool that I can use which have the functionality like a mac terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481685/setting-colors-for-prompt-in-git-bash-on-windows). It should help.

In your .bashrc you can set your prompt using the PS1 variable (which is likely set to a global value in /etc/profile or another file in /etc which may be distribution dependent).

Here's a example

```
PS1='\[\033[1;36m\]\u@\h:\[\033[0m\]\[\033[1;34m\]\w\[\033[0m\] \[\033[1;32m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[0m\]\$ '
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Thank you..where can i find the .bashrc in windows?

Comment: Try this vi ~/.bashrc

Comment: I pasted the above example command on that and saved aswell. But still no changes.

Comment: Did you restart the terminal. You have to do that. Also try source ~/.bashrc

Comment: Yes I tried it again by restarting the server. But no changes

Comment: You could also try to change the settings from the Git Bash properties. It should be somewhere in the main menu or should be in the box that appears when right click. Also try some git config commands as **git config --global color.ui auto** or **git config --global --add color.ui**

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. But its still not working